# output standard error for odds ratio in logistic regression

Tags: sas

I am running a logistic regression in SAS. SAS output odds ratio estimates with point estimate and 95% confidence limit. How can I output standard error in odds ratio output (not in parameter estimates) together with point estimate and 95% confidence limit

```
proc logistic data=data1;
class rank / param=ref;
model admit = gre gpa rank; 
run;
```

This is the output for odds ratio estimate, how can I make SAS add standard error for odds ratio estimate?

```
                                  Odds Ratio Estimates

                                      Point          95% Wald
                    Effect         Estimate      Confidence Limits

                    GRE               1.002       1.000       1.004
                    GPA               2.235       1.166       4.282
                    RANK 1 vs 4       4.718       2.080      10.701
                    RANK 2 vs 4       2.401       1.170       4.927
                    RANK 3 vs 4       1.235       0.572       2.668
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Since odds ratio is simply `exp(Estimate)` reported in `Analysis of Maximum Likelihood Estimates` could taking `exp(Standard
Error)` reported in the same table be what you are looking for?

Comment: try putting `expb` in your model statement.  like...
`model admit = gre gpa rank / expb;`

Comment: @neymar were you able to solve this question ? if so, could you please post the answer to it. Thanks.